# How to send data in secure way between client and server using only Symmetric cryptography

Tags: security, cryptography, encryption-symmetric

I'd take the following steps to send/received data between client and server. But I'm not sure if all the steps are secure enough and impossible to intercept. Please can you let me know how to patch up the security holes, if any?
Please note that:

This is all for Symmetric cryptography not the Public/Private Key method. So 'salt' and 'entropy' are the secrets between client and server.

For some reasons, I cannot/don't use SSL or TLS protocols. So there is no Certificate Authority etc.

Only standard cryptography functions and methods must be used (no inventions).

The data are not sent over a secure (HTTPS) connection.

I cannot use sessions here because they are two different applications.

**First time - Sign up** (user enters new username and new password)

1. *Client side*

   1. Create a CSPRNG salt for the user
     1. Save salt on user's machine
   2. Create an entropy in memory (base64 of a temporal value e.g. [hour of the day]+[day of the year])
   3. Post Password(base64 of the plaintext), and salt, and entropy to the server
2. *Server side*

   1. For the received message from the cliet
     1. Check if entropy matches (e.g. with base64 of [hour of the day]+[day of the year]) .
     2. Compute hash (SHA1) of salt and Password(base64 of the plaintext) - because hashing must always be done on the server.
     3. Save salt and the computed hash to the database

**Next time - Log in** (user enters his username and his password)

1. *Client side*

   1. Read salt from user's machine
   2. Compute hash (SHA1) of salt and entered password(base64 of the plaintext)
   3. Post password(base64 of the plaintext), and salt, and the computed hash to the server
2. *Server side*

   1. Retrieve salt and 'stored hash' from the database
   2. From the received message from the client
     1. Split the message to 3 parts: password(base64 of the paintext); salt; 'received hash'
     2. Compare 'received hash' with 'stored hash'; if they match, the user is genuine not a hacker

**Sending TemperProof queryString from user to server**

1. *Client side*

   1. Read salt from user's machine
   2. Create an entropy in memory (base64 of a temporal value e.g. [hour of the day]+[day of the year])
   3. Compute hash (SHA1) of the queryString(base64 of the plaintext), and salt, and entropy
   4. Post querystring(base64 of the plaintext), and salt, and entropy, and the computed hash to the server
2. *Server side*

   1. Retrieve salt from the database
   2. For the received message from the cliet
     1. Split the message to 4 parts: queryString(base64 of the paintext); salt; entropy; 'received hash'
     2. Check if entropy matches (e.g. with base64 of [hour of the day]+[day of the year]) .
     3. Compute hash (SHA1) of queryString(base64 of the plaintext) and salt and entropy.
     4. Compare the computed hash with the 4th part of the splitted message ('received hash'); if they match, the queryString is genuine

**Sending answer back to the user from server**

1. *Server side*

   1. Compute the answer using database queries
   2. Retrieve salt from the database
   3. Create an entropy in memory (base64 of a temporal value e.g. [hour of the day]+[day of the year])
   4. Compute hash (SHA1) of the answer(base64 of the plaintext), and salt, and entropy
   5. Post answer(base64 of the plaintext), and salt, and entropy, and the computed hash to the client
2. *Client side*

   1. Read salt from user's machine
   2. Create an entropy in memory (base64 of a temporal value e.g. [hour of the day]+[day of the year])
   3. Split the received message to 4 parts: answer(base64 of the paintext); salt; entropy; 'received hash'
   4. Check if entropy matches (e.g. with base64 of [hour of the day]+[day of the year]) .
   5. Compute hash (SHA1) of answer(base64 of the plaintext) and salt and entropy.
   6. Compare the computed hash with the 4th part of the splitted message ('received hash'); if they match, the answer is genuine

**The followings areas are the weaknesses, I think. Can you please advise how these can be fixed and also point out the other possible holes?**

  A)
  *First time - Sign up:*
  The hacker can post rubbish to fill up the database, if he finds entropy in step 1.3

  B)
  *Next time - Log in:*
  I cannot think of a way to add an entropy to the hashed password in step 1.2, because then I cannot compare with the one on the server database in step 2.2.2

Thanks

Comment: 1. Do you want a secure system? If so do not design your own system, use proven methods. 2. You say: "no inventions" buit the whole scheme is an invention of the worst kind: overly complicated. 3. ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.

Comment: I do not think it is secure at all as base64 is not an encryption and as far as I see a man in the middle could get all the information needed to impersonate either side. To ensure that a man in the middle cannot easily break into the communication you need a shared secret between client and server and I just don't see where something like this comes into play.

Comment: @Frank, As you noticed this is all for Symmetric cryptography not the Public Key method. So  'salt'  and 'entropy' are the secret between client and server.

Comment: I don't get what's so secret about a base64 encoded "entropy" transferred via unsecure channel...

Comment: @Zaph, I  didn't invent a thing. Majority of my design are based on the training course that I had on Pluralsight, which I presume are the very standard procedure for password protection, etc., so .

Comment: @Frank, I updated the question based on the comments I received. Thanks for referring to the issue with base64 encoded "entropy". This is exactly the one I mentioned in my question (see A- First time - Sign up: The hacker can post rubbish to fill up the database, if he finds entropy in step 1.3). I need a solution for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The solution is to use HTTPS withTLS 1.2 and pin the certificate, there are certificate solutions that are free.
2. Using a hash (SHA1 in this case) to protect a password has not been good secure practice for some time. For my reference see [DRAFT NIST Special Publication 800-63B Digital Authentication Guideline](https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html).
3. Passwords must be protected with an iterated HMAC, not a single hash. For more information on passwords see [Toward Better Password Requirements](http://www.slideshare.net/jim_fenton/toward-better-password-requirements) by Jim Fenton, see slide 23 in particular. This seems to be at odds with the Pluralsight training, best practices have changes over time.

Answer (score 2):

if you care about security at all, STOP now ...

what you need to do:

1) forget about designing your own crypto protocol ... relying on well known crypto ALSO means that you DO NOT design that kind of thing

2) think in layers ... you have the need to keep things secret while transporting them from A to B ... that means you have a transport layer ... if you want that secured, there is a name for that...
**T**ransport **L**ayer **S**ecurity -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

3) when you make assumptions here like "i have 2 applications so i can not have sessions", please provide WHY you think it is that way... when you think of things like single-sign-on, you can have a lot of applications sharing one authentication method and even session data across a bunch of different plattforms ... maybe it's just you don't know that you actually *can* have sessions...

4) read up on the terms you use ... you misunderstood entropy ... there is no way of "checking if entropy matches" ... entropy in crypto related cases means randomness in terms of unpredictable input to a function ... if you have something like a date and the time, and even if you hash that, it might look random ... but it is very predictable by someone with a clock... if the communication can be related to the creation time of the value, then your value does not contain large amounts of entropy if it is based on the clock... again, do not design you own stuff here, and go for entropy sources that provide reliable, cryptographically secure randomness (CSPRNG ... not just PRNG)

5) ... you misunderstood/misused salt... 
that is nothing to be generated on the client machine
that is nothing that needs to be kept on the client machine

7) password hashing
again ... DO NOT come up with you own stuff here ...
create a sufficently long random salt (at least hash length) for every password. use a slow hash function like PBKDF2 with a high iteration count parameter. the reason is that it becomes slow to test for passwords... your server has to calculate this once for every login attempt ... an attacker has to calculate this for every password testing attempt ... you can afford the test to take like 200ms ... for an attacker that means a lot more hardware will be needed to crack your password storage...

**upd:**
you want it, you get it ...

proof of concept attack on your schema by man-in-the-middle:

client: alice
server: bob
attacker/eavesdropper: eve

1. alice uses your sign up service and creates an account
   1.1 alice creates a CSPRNG salt and stores that in a secure manner
   1.2 alice gathers an arbitrary amount of entropy and encodes it with base64
   1.3 alice sends Password(base64 of the plaintext), and salt, and entropy to bob
   ------------intercepted-------------
2. eve intercepts the communication between alice and bob and gains knowledge of...
   2.1 ...the base 64 encoded password -> base64 decode -> the plaintext password
   2.2 ...the salt
   2.3 ...the entropy value
   2.4 alice forwards the intercepted communication without changes to bob

--- protocol broken ---
now, bob is by no means able to distinguish between alice and eve in all further communication

**upd2:**

a look on your transfered (cleartext) messages:
Login:
Post password(base64 of the plaintext), and salt, and the computed hash to the server
Sending queryString from user to server:
Post querystring(base64 of the plaintext), and salt, and entropy, and the computed hash to the server
answer:
Post answer(base64 of the plaintext), and salt, and entropy, and the computed hash to the client

now for any of those messages, let's look at what information someone with malicious intent would learn from those:

all the information that is cleartext, which means, all of it ... 
for the login, we gain the clear text password, means from now on an attacker can identify as a valid user

for the querystring and answer thing you want to provide a way to see if the request/answer is not tempered with.

so if an attacker now intercepts your communication how can he change the querystring without being noticed?
the attacker splits your message, and changes whatever he/she wants
then he/she computates the forged_hash as sha1(salt_from_the_original_message,tampered_querystring) and sends base64(tampered_querystring),salt_from_the_original_message,entropy_from_original_message,forged_hash to the server ...

for the answer it's the same deal:

the attacker intercepts the original answer, changes whatever in the answer and recomputes the hash based on known information (the changes, and the original salt)

Comment: thanks for the answer. I just updated the question with more information and actually limitations I have here. This is all for Symmetric cryptography not the Public/Private Key method. So I cannot/don't use SSL or TLS protocols. Your perception of 'salt' and 'entropy' is far different from the training course that I had on Pluralsight. Majority of the things in my design are base on the training course, which I presume are the very standard procedure for password protection, etc., so I  didn't invent a thing.

Comment: @CloudWindMoonSun 1. DarkSquirrel42 is correct. 2. What you learned from Pluralsight is incorrect, wondering what course you took. 3. Why can't you use HTTPS?

Comment: @zaph, 1. I think Pluralsight training are very high quality and I doubt if they are wrong. 2. HTTPS, SSL, TLS need money, which is not available for my research project.

Comment: fun fact: by information theory it is provable that your problem ***can not*** be solved by symetric crypto ...

Comment: @CloudWindMoonSun i usually tend to be more polite when is say something like this but please let me be as clear as possible here: what you are doing is bullshit and way beyond repair ... your information level about what you are doing is very poor, and i can not believe you did this AFTER a even only somewhat qualified course about cryptographic security measures... so please... refer to standard solutions rather than to things you just presume to be standard ... if you ship the client, then even the info that you need a paid cert for TLS is wrong...

Comment: @CloudWindMoonSun 1. There may be a disconnect between the information Pluralsight is providing and what you are understanding. 2. The information Pluralsight may be old. 3. In particular using a hash (SHA1 in this case) to protect a password has not been good secure practice for some time. For my reference see [DRAFT NIST Special Publication 800-63B Digital Authentication Guideline](
https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html).

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42, so password creation and validation cannot be done securely using symmetric cryptography at all. I was very dubious about it since I couldn't come up with a solution for questions A and B, and now you find yet another similar hole. But I think the last two scenarios for QueryString and Answer in my question should work. Can you think of any flaw in those two cases?

Comment: @CloudWindMoonSun ... you are mixing up things again ... i never said that password creation and validation can not be pretected by symetric crypto ... i supposed your problem was having a single client being handed out to users and creating accounts with that out of the box ... if you just want to secure password creation and verification, hand out pre-generated and server-side-known symetric keys to your users on another secure channel ... problem solved ... but as you will see, that's not a usually practicable solution

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42, ahhh, I just read your previous comment. I don't see why you're insulting me. People with different abilities ask questions on StackOverflow. That's the whole point of this community. If you want to insult people go somewhere else. You are not forced to answer the questions you find silly. Please I don't want to hear anything more from you.

Comment: ok, for the sake of completeness: none of your communication protocol steps are providing ANY cryptographic strength against MITM attacks ... in other words: either you are just another troll, or you messed up what you could mess up without realizing a thing... if you learned that on a paid course, i would recommend asking for a refund...

Comment: @zaph, thanks for the link, I shall read through them later. Do you agree that password creation and validation cannot be done by Symmetric cryptography? Do you agree that last two scenarios for QueryString and Answer in my question should work with Symmetric crypto?

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42, sorry I don't like your language. Please don't blot my question with your words. Sorry you are not welcomed here.

Comment: @CloudWindMoonSun ... sorry if you feel attacked by this in any way, it's not my intention to insult you or anything. if you don't want my advice, i'm totally fine with that. but let me ask you one question: would you rather have your protocol taken apart by me, or another hacker giving it a funny look after you build the whole thing?

Comment: @CloudWindMoonSun The solutions the use HTTPS withTLS 1.2 and pin the certificate, there are certificate solutions that are free. Passwords must be protected with an iterated HMAC, not a single hash. For more information on passwords see [Toward Better Password Requirements](http://www.slideshare.net/jim_fenton/toward-better-password-requirements) by Jim Fenton, see slide 23 in particular. RThis seems to be at odds with the Pluralsight training.

Comment: updated answer for completeness, added proof of mitm for all protocol messages

Comment: @zaph, awesome. That's what I really need here, pointers to the right direction. Pointers to practical stuff. Many thanks for the link. Obviously training courses and reading books on their own are not always sufficient. I hope you save me from people on StackOverflow who just criticize and insult, without providing any practical useful hints too.

Comment: @zaph, if you put the links you suggested in the form of an answer to this question, I will mark it as the "Answer".